# Can't get bash working with i3wm

Tags: i3-wm

No matter what i try i can't get ash terminal to work on i3wm apart from xterm, all i wanted was a bash window.

Have the same problem as this thread only xterm works so all the solutions are useless

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/6um2e4/noob_question_fresh_install_i3_starting_but_not/

So far only xterm lxterm and gnome-terminal worked

Comment: What release/flavor of Ubuntu?, or are you even running Ubuntu ?  What error if any do you get?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.3 minimal with the error of  Not a managed window, ignoring UnmapNotify event but i think i mixed shell and terminal terms so i'm having an issue with the terminal while shell might be correct checking it now

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, and there was no 2018-March release of Ubuntu.

Comment: I meant the last LTS that is 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I mixed Shell and Terminal Emulator in the terminology apparently i had the shell working a while back and xterm just need some configuration changes to work properly (also i got rid of gnome-terminal)
Sorry my bad

As suggested below i'm adding more details to this.
I've installed Ubuntu Mini with nothing more
Installed I3wm
Installed Zsh
Installed Tmux
All via Apt
Created .xinitrc and added exec i3 to start i3wm when x starts,
followed the zsh official instructions when changing shell which is running chsh -s $(which zsh)
Also you can check the Env variables to see the SHELL changed to that path.

Regarding .zshrc there is an if i copied from bashrc that checks if the current terminal is tty1 and then runs startx, this is so you can easily start everything once you logged in in the first terminal and still keep the ability to have other terminal without running the same

There is also a line there to start tmux with every zsh session

Regarding the Terminal that i confused it was because it was white and black text i've changed to colors to black and light gray text and create .Xdefaults file to keep it like that

I also had some apps from snap like vscode which i had to add to PATH in .zshrc to make sure Dmenu populated those in there (i3 works with demnu) and i have set up i3bar to work with Conky per official guide on i3wm website plus the entries which i needed.

**TLDR version**

apt install i3

apt install zsh

apt install tmux

**.xinitrc**

```
exec i3
```

**.Xdefaults**

```
xterm*background: black
xterm*foreground: lightgray
```

**.zshrc**

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin:$HOME/start:$PATH

if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
startx
fi

[[ $TERM = "xterm" ]] && { tmux && exit 0; }
```

Comment: Sure, already done

Comment: Thanks for expanding this!